# Mapping for triangular meshes to another 3d shape

Tags: python, matlab, geometry, computational-geometry

I was trying to code a bounded distortion mapping for triangular meshes. Like, suppose I have a triangular mesh for a sphere.

```matlab
[V,F] = subdivided_sphere(1);
tsurf(F,V); axis equal;
```

[image: triangular-mesh-sphere]

where `V` and `F` are,

```matlab
V =

            0      0.52573      0.85065
            0     -0.52573      0.85065
            0      0.52573     -0.85065
            0     -0.52573     -0.85065
      0.52573      0.85065            0
     -0.52573      0.85065            0
      0.52573     -0.85065            0
     -0.52573     -0.85065            0
      0.85065            0      0.52573
     -0.85065            0      0.52573
      0.85065            0     -0.52573
     -0.85065            0     -0.52573
            0            0            1
      0.30902      0.80902          0.5
     -0.30902      0.80902          0.5
          0.5      0.30902      0.80902
         -0.5      0.30902      0.80902
      0.30902     -0.80902          0.5
     -0.30902     -0.80902          0.5
          0.5     -0.30902      0.80902
         -0.5     -0.30902      0.80902
            0            0           -1
      0.30902      0.80902         -0.5
     -0.30902      0.80902         -0.5
          0.5      0.30902     -0.80902
         -0.5      0.30902     -0.80902
      0.30902     -0.80902         -0.5
     -0.30902     -0.80902         -0.5
          0.5     -0.30902     -0.80902
         -0.5     -0.30902     -0.80902
            0            1            0
      0.80902          0.5      0.30902
      0.80902          0.5     -0.30902
     -0.80902          0.5      0.30902
     -0.80902          0.5     -0.30902
            0           -1            0
      0.80902         -0.5      0.30902
      0.80902         -0.5     -0.30902
     -0.80902         -0.5      0.30902
     -0.80902         -0.5     -0.30902
            1            0            0
           -1            0            0
F =

     1    13    16
     1    16    14
     1    14    15
     1    15    17
     1    17    13
     2    18    20
     9    37    41
     9    41    32
     5    33    23
     5    23    31
     6    24    35
     6    35    34
    10    42    39
    10    39    21
     2    19    18
     4    27    28
     4    28    30
     4    30    22
     4    22    29
     4    29    27
     2    20    13
     9    32    16
     5    31    14
     6    34    15
    10    21    17
     7    37    18
     7    38    37
    11    33    41
    11    25    33
     3    24    23
     3    26    24
    12    42    35
    12    40    42
     8    19    39
     8    36    19
     7    36    27
     8    40    28
    12    26    30
     3    25    22
    11    38    29
     9    16    20
     5    14    32
     6    15    31
    10    17    34
     2    13    21
     9    20    37
    11    41    38
     5    32    33
     3    23    25
     6    31    24
    12    35    26
    10    34    42
     8    39    40
     2    21    19
     7    18    36
     8    28    36
    12    30    40
     3    22    26
    11    29    25
     7    27    38
    20    16    13
    32    14    16
    31    15    14
    34    17    15
    21    13    17
    37    20    18
    38    41    37
    33    32    41
    25    23    33
    24    31    23
    26    35    24
    42    34    35
    40    39    42
    19    21    39
    36    18    19
    36    28    27
    40    30    28
    26    22    30
    25    29    22
    38    27    29
```

I was trying to learn/understand how the mapping was constructed to transform a 3d shape (triangular meshes) to another 3d shape with distortion or without distortion for one of my personal project. I googled and get bounded mapping are the best one because they are supposed to be bijective, and I could reverse the map. And if you think I should read any book before understanding these things, then please suggest one. My main goal is to learn how to define this kind of mapping.

Providing any python/matlab code or a paper where these things were described in details will be a great help for me. Sorry, if this question was too basic as I was learning geometry processing by my own.

Comment: A mapping should map every point of the mesh to a different space. However, you didn't provide any space for the destination. Is it a mapping from a sphere to a different 3D shape with the same topology? Or is it a mapping to a 2D space where you'll have to "cut" some parts of the sphere? How many cuts are acceptable?

Comment: "to a different 3D shape": which shape ?

Comment: Anything which perverse topology. My main goal is to learn how to define this kind of mapping @YvesDaoust

Comment: That does not make sense. It you don't specify how the target shape is defined, the question cannot be answered.

Comment: Aha, I see. Because without specifying the target shape, there are infinite choice to transform it into another 3D shape. Okay, Then I am interested in a sphere with some distortion. I am interested in distortion because I want to see how to change it into some non-identical shape. That's the main reason. @YvesDaoust

Answer (score 1):

**From Surface to Plane**

Here are two papers about bounded distortion mapping of triangular meshes:

[Bounded Distortion Mapping Spaces for Triangular Meshes](https://www.cs.jhu.edu/%7Emisha/ReadingSeminar/Papers/Lipman12.pdf), Lipman, 2012. ([Matlab Code](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/%7Eylipman/BoundedDistortion/BD_EQC.zip))
[Bounded Distortion Parametrization in the Space of Metrics](http://www.eng.biu.ac.il/%7Eweberof/Publications/Metric-Param/Bounded_Distortion_Parametrization_in_the_Space_of_Metrics.pdf), Chien, Levi, and Weber. 2016.

Both of these papers deal with mapping a triangular mesh to a 2D space assuming that the triangular mesh has been cut to have the topology of a disk.

This paper creates a bounded distortion mapping to a 2D space while doing the cut at the same time:

[Bounded-distortion Piecewise Mesh Parameterization](https://igl.ethz.ch/projects/parameterization/BDPMP/sorkine02.pdf)

**From Surface to Surface**

[Lifted Bijections for Low Distortion Surface Mappings](https://noamaig.github.io/html/projects/lifted/lifted.pdf), Aigerman et al., 2014.
[Seemless surface mapping](https://noamaig.github.io/html/projects/seamless/seamless.pdf), Aigerman et al., 2015.
[ENIGMA: Evolutionary Non-Isometric Geometry MAtching](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/%7Emirela/publications/enigma.pdf), Edelstein et al., 2020.

These are just some examples of papers and techniques that deals with bijective maps of surfaces, but you can look at the previous works and references for more information. I mentioned these ones because they are the main teams that started dealing with bijective maps.

Another paper that I like but that doesn't guarantee the bijectivity property:

[Fitting polynomial surfaces to triangular meshes with Voronoi squared distance minimization](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-00763898/document)

It uses the "shrink wrap" technique but in a much more robust way.

And a last review paper (outdated but still useful to get the basics) for mapping surfaces to a sphere (you can reverse the map to get sphere-to-surface):

[Fundamentals of Spherical Parameterization for 3D Meshes](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Esheffa/papers/SigCDV.pdf)

**Other Resources**

[Discrete Differential Geometry: An Applied Introduction](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ekmcrane/Projects/DDG/paper.pdf)
[Polygon Mesh Processing](http://www.pmp-book.org/) (Book)

Comment: Thanks for your response @Gilles-Philippe Paillé. I forgot to mention that I  want to map the sphere to a different 3D shape with the same topology. It will be a great help if you provide that. Thanks again.

Comment: @WhyMeasureTheory I see! Before editing my answer, I would also need to know what you consider "distortion-free". For some applications, conformal maps are considered to be without distortion because they locally only introduce a uniform scale. Some other application could interpret any deviation from a rotation matrix to be distorted. Also, does the user need to provide a bound himself?

Comment: To be honest, I am not super familiar with geometry processing. I was trying to learn/understand how the functional map was constructed to transform a 3d shape to another 3d shape with distortion or without distortion for one of my personal project. I googled and get bounded mapping are the best one because they are supposed to be bijective, and I could reverse the map. And if you think I should read any book before understanding these things, then please suggest one. I know Linear Algebra, Real Analysis, Complex Analysis and a little bit of Differential Geometry. @Gilles-Philippe Paillé.

Comment: @WhyMeasureTheory I linked some more papers for bijective surface-to-surface mappings. Note that if you allow for non-bijective maps (with some amount of overlaps), then the concept of "lift" can be applied to many other existing non-bijective mapping from a surface a sphere. For example, many papers in conformal mapping deal with mapping a surface to a sphere. Then, if you map both surface to the sphere, you can get a surface-to-surface map by using the sphere as a way to connect points of the two surfaces.

Comment: I go through each paper you suggested and found [Fundamentals of Spherical Parameterization for 3D Meshes](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Esheffa/papers/SigCDV.pdf) the suitable for my problem. But the problem is, I'm afraid that I couldn't regenerate the code by my own (as I have no prior knowledge).

Comment: Meanwhile, I got [open3d](http://www.open3d.org/docs/0.10.0/tutorial/Advanced/mesh_deformation.html) which implement [As Rigid As Possible Surface Modeling](https://igl.ethz.ch/projects/ARAP/arap_web.pdf). I was wondering is there any existing package/git repo where I can find the code for Fundamentals of Spherical Parameterization for 3D Meshes. @Gilles-Philippe Paillé. And thanks for your effort, now I feel, I at least know what I am looking for.